# Can I place an archway here?

Tags: new-home

[image: I want to place archways instead of walls on the three places as shown in picture.]

I want to place archways instead of walls on the three places as shown in picture. The Wall are made of solid bricks. RCC slabs. No timber, no steel.
 Do you think it is safe because I want to make another floor above this floor. The total plot area of the house is about 12m X12m. There are Beams and columns on every corner of wall are about 1ft X1ft.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Interesting question, but you'll have to consult an on-site structural engineer, especially as you're adding a floor. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of archways: 1) superficial archways, and 2) true archways.

1) Superficial archways are merely regular openings (with a header and support) that have archways framed down to mimic true archways.

2) True archways create a thrust outward that needs to be resisted with supports starting from where the arch starts. This support can be another arch (like the Roman aqueducts) or just an extended wall.

Your house could have archways if you designed an adequate size beam (header), support posts at each end, and adequate size footings under each post.

However, you cannot have a true arch in the up and down direction because there is nothing to support the outward thrust. (You might be able to have a braced wall in the side to side direction.)

Regardless , you’ll need to carefully calculate all the loads transferred down from above on each arch, then determine the load transferred down to the footings.